# What are the runtime debuggers available in AIX? for the C language?

Tags: debugging

What are the runtime debuggers available in AIX? for the C language?
I know we have 
dbx - Crap

---

gdb - Good but doesnt work.

Any other?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? And you still haven't said which compiler you are using.

Comment: What does it matter which compliler i use..i can use xlc or gcc or anyother..
how does debugger get affected by it?.

Comment: Believe it or not, you can't use any old debugger with any old compiler - the debug info format for the compiler has to be compatible with the debugger, to start with.

Comment: So you are saying that if i compile a executable or a shared lib with xlc ...I cannot debug with gdb?
Btw i m not using any old compiler or debugger..
i use xlc v9 i think and gdb 6.x they are new i guess..

Answer (score 2):

For xlC there is dbx and the GUI frontend xdbx.

Answer (score 1):

Totalview. Best debugger for AIX by a country mile. Interface is old hat motif but functionally very good. Great at threads by the way.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Debugger - /usr/idebug/idebug

GNU Debugger should also work - /opt/freeware/bin/gdb

Answer (score -1):

Are you asking about AIX's native C compiler? If so consult your IBM saleman. You can of course run [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on AIX, and use the gdb debugger. This has a number of front-ends for it, the best of which is probably [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/).

Comment: if i ask IBM sales..they will sell me crap like dbx..
Do u really want crap or u want something working..?
Just becoz IBM makes these tool doesn't mean they work..

Comment: Sorry, I have a pathological dislike of people who think it is "kewel" not to spell properly. I won't be answering any more of your questions here.